# Auto add row in table HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an table in my page that lists User and Email when user sends this information
How I can make this table add an row for each post and not delete other line?

My aspx

```
<table id="tblUsers" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody id="tbodyUser">
            <tr>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Visible="false">User to Access</asp:Label>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My .cs

```
protected void btnSendUser_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LoginInfo = txtUserAdd.Text;
    PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "x.com", "amsndrsecuritysqlser", "xxx");
    UserPrincipal insUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(insPrincipalContext, LoginInfo);


    //it's to first post
    if (lblUser.Visible == false && lblEmail.Visible == false)
    {
        if (insUserPrincipal == null)
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }

        else
        {
            lblUser.Visible = true;
            lblEmail.Visible = true;
            lblHeader.Visible = true;
            lblUser.Text = insUserPrincipal.GivenName + " " + insUserPrincipal.Surname;
            lblEmail.Text = insUserPrincipal.EmailAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add `runat="server"` to your table `tblUsers`

```
var row =new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
var cell = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = "New Cell";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
tblUsers.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Happy to help you, in end of btnSendUser_OnClick

Comment: Sorry, not added one more row for each "btnSendUser_OnClick". It's replacing value at my previous row and in row below, write the same thing. I get the same information in two lines. And it's create just one column information ("UserName").

Comment: I replace "New Cell" to insUserPrincipal.GivenName + " " + insUserPrincipal.Surname;

Answer (score 0):

It would be one of some possible solutions:

1. Store your data in a collection
2. In every button click, update the data and put it in session
3. Bind the session data to a Repeater in your page (the binding code MUST be in Page_Load)

The Repeater markup would be something like this

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tbody id="tbodyUser">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Visible="<% #lblHeaderVisibilty %>">User to Access</asp:Label>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Visible="<% #lblUserVisibilty %>"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Visible="<% #lblEmailVisibilty %>"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```